# Which features does ZSH use timestamp history for?

Tags: zsh, command-history

zsh history includes a timestamp, with the option to disable it.

Beyond knowing when a command was executed, what's the reason for this? What features might I lose if I disable this?

Comment: Why isn't that sufficient reason?

Comment: Sure, but if thats the _only_ reason. I'd happily disable it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

zsh history includes a timestamp, if the `EXTENDED_HISTORY` feature is enabled, or if the `SHARE_HISTORY` feature is enabled; in the latter case, timestamps are used so multiple shells can *read* each others’ history accurately — they only need to read any new commands added since the last time they read the history file, and they can do so even when the history file is rewritten.

These features are enabled or disabled using `setopt`:

```
setopt extendedhistory
setopt sharehistory
```

will enable them, while

```
setopt noextendedhistory
setopt nosharehistory
```

will disable them.

If you want to keep shared histories, you’ll need to keep the extended timestamps (but you don’t need to explicitly enable the `EXTENDED_HISTORY` feature; the `SHARE_HISTORY` feature is self-sufficient).

Note that extended history tells you not only *when* a command was executed, but also *how long* it took to run, which can be useful in some cases.

The [History section](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#History) of the documentation has all the details.

Answer (score 4):

If I recall correctly, ZSH uses the time stamp to reorder the historical commands when you have more than one session opened.